# unable to assign value from python dictionary to variable

Tags: python, dictionary, get

I am trying to assign a value to variable from a dictionary but unable to do so.

I have tried:

```
self.currency = inflationcurrency[self.currency]
self.currency = inflationcurrency.get([self.currency])
```

on the top I have tried declaring self.currency as

```
self.currency = ''.join(self.tempholder[0])
```

This is the code:

```
import string

datatype = "Inflation SABR Vol ATM ZC"
dataconvention = "UK-RPI-ZERO-COUPON-SWAP-RATE"
mdlname = "INFLATION_SABR"
t1 = 'should-send-back-none'

class srtqualifier:
    def __init__(self,mdlname,datatype, dataconvention,t1):
        self.mdlname = mdlname
        self.datatype = datatype
        self.dataconvention = dataconvention
        self.t1 = t1 ##TO BE REMOVED, ONLY USE FOR TESTING##
        self.tempholder =  self.dataconvention.split("-")
        self.currency = self.tempholder[0]

    def curr(self):
        if self.mdlname == "INFLATION_SABR":
            inflationcurrency = {'UK':'GBP','FR':'EUR','EU':'EUR','US':'USD'}
            self.currency = inflationcurrency.get(self.currency)
        else:
            return self.currency

        def makequalifier(self):
        qualifier = string.join([self.currency,"|",self.spartSABR(),"|",self.modelname(),"|",self.dttype(),"|",self.lastpart()])
        return qualifier 

test1 = srtqualifier(mdlname,datatype,dataconvention,t1)
print(test1.makequalifier())
```

The error on above is expected string but recieved Nonetype from self.currency

I get none when I do below.

```
print (test1.currency())
```

Comment: Put a `pdb`, your split could be returning `None`?

Comment: split is not returning none. Spilt is returning 'UK'

Comment: `self.currency` evaluates to `GBP`, but inflationcurrency is a dictionary with country as key like `UK` etc. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Nishant that is the intended value for currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using currency both as variable and as a method, rename one of them.

--- Edit ---

You are not returning in the curr method.

```
def curr(self):
    if self.mdlname == "INFLATION_SABR":
        inflationcurrency = {'UK':'GBP','FR':'EUR','EU':'EUR','US':'USD'}
        self.currency = inflationcurrency.get(self.currency)
    return self.currency
```

This should work.

Comment: You are not returning the self.currency in the curr method if. If you delete the "else:" and unindent the return line, it should work.

Comment: I was just thinking about that and there seems to be something else going on currency and specondpart are both ''None'' while that should never be. Editing the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing it correctly? `inflationcurrency` doesn't have a key by the name `GBP`.

```
(Pdb) self.currency
'GBP'

Pdb) inflationcurrency
{'EU': 'EUR', 'FR': 'EUR', 'US': 'USD', 'UK': 'GBP'}
```

Reverse your key-value to make it work?

```
inflationcurrency = {'EUR': ['EUR', 'FR'], 'USD': 'US', 'GBP': 'UK'}
```